# Step into referenced .Net 3.5 assembly from Asp.Net 4 project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-3.5, .net-4.0

Can I step into .net 3.5 assembly that is referenced by an Asp.Net 4 application?

We have a bunch of dll's that are used in our projects. The assemblies are targeting framework 3.5. I also have the source code for the assemblies. In framework 3.5 projects I could step into the referenced assemblies, even though the project only referenced the assemblies, if I set the Solution->Properties->Debug Source Files -setting to the location of the assemblies' source code files. Now in an Asp.Net 4 project the same doesn't work. I cannot step into the referenced code.

If I open a source file directly in Visual Studio (File-Open->navigate to source code location) and put a breakpoint in a file I know will be run it says "...breakpoint will not be hit. No symbols have been loaded..." when attaching to w3wp.exe and selecting to debug "Managed (4.0)". If I attach it to "Managed (2.0)" the breakpoint does not hit either.

Please advice,
Mathias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have your compiled dlls under 3.5 framework, and also you have source code for them, right? Have you tried opening a solution, which contains the project, and attaching it to w3wp.exe? Also ensure your dlls were compiled with debug information.

Another way is to use [.NET Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/) to step in dlls without source code at all.

Comment: This works. I opened the "framework"-solution, attached it to the asp.net 4.0 process and now I can debug the code. Thanks a lot!